# I migrated an app from React to Nextjs but didn't notice index.html was set up 365 day cache

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I took over a React app, updated and migrated it to Nextjs. I also moved it from Netlify to Vercel. I didn't predict there would be issues with caching - previous site visitors see the old website. What ways can I tackle this problem? I realize I should've paid attention to that, and update the previous website with a request to clear cache/hard reload, but I didn't.

I've tried adding a cache-control-headers.ts file with the following:

```
import type { NextApiResponse, NextApiRequest } from 'next';
 
export default function handler(
request: NextApiRequest,
response: NextApiResponse,
) {
response.setHeader('Vercel-CDN-Cache-Control', 'max-age=3600');
response.setHeader('CDN-Cache-Control', 'max-age=60');
response.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=10');

return response.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' });
}
```

and it solved it on some systems/browsers, but not all.
I've tried redirecting (302 and 307) from domain.com to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) to circumvent the issue but it's not redirecting.